# VBScript watchdog

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to create a script that will look at a specific .txt file on the local computer, get it's DateLastModified attribute, and compare it to the last/previous value when it was last checked (in a loop, every 1-2 seconds).

The loop (running every second) would increment a counter, and if the counter reaches a limit (say 10 seconds), a section of code would perform a task of "kill/terminate" a specific process/.exe that is likely hung up, and restart it.

I've found some pretty good samples of .vbs online that use subscription events, I don't think this is the route I want/need to go, as the script actually needs to be continuously running and not asynchronously only when the specific file is modified.

**Edit**: I am looking for a VBScript that provides a "watchdog" function, by monitoring a .txt file for modifications. The script should run a loop every second that checks for modifications, and if no modifications, increments a counter. Once the counter reaches a limit (10 seconds?) it would terminate a fixed process (hardcoded as a parameter in the VBScript), and then relaunch the process (path to the process as a parameter in the VBScript).

I haven't found a good example to share thus far. I've been playing with other examples that utilize the `objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery(Query)` which seems cool in that little overhead is used (asynchronous in nature) -- it does not appear to fit my needs as described above.

If I must share what I've found and been toying with... OK... here it is:

```
intInterval = "1"
strDrive = "C:"
strFolder = "\\Project\\"
strComputer = "."
intTmrVal = 0

Set objWMIService = GetObject( "winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2" )

strQuery = "Select * From __InstanceOperationEvent" _
    & " Within " & intInterval _
    & " Where Targetinstance Isa 'CIM_DataFile'" _
    & " And TargetInstance.Name='C:\\Project\\test.txt'"

Set colEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery(strQuery)

Do
    Set objEvent = colEvents.NextEvent()
    Set objTargetInst = objEvent.TargetInstance

    Select Case objEvent.Path_.Class
        Case "__InstanceCreationEvent"
            WScript.Echo "Created: " & objTargetInst.Name
        Case "__InstanceDeletionEvent"
            WScript.Echo "Deleted: " & objTargetInst.Name
        Case "__InstanceModificationEvent"
            Set objPrevInst = objEvent.PreviousInstance

            For Each objProperty In objTargetInst.Properties_
                If objProperty.Value <> objPrevInst.Properties_(objProperty.Name) Then
                    WScript.Echo "Changed:        " & objTargetInst.Name
                    WScript.Echo "Property:       " & objProperty.Name
                    WScript.Echo "Previous value: " & objPrevInst.Properties_(objProperty.Name)
                    WScript.Echo "New value:      " & objProperty.Value
                End If
            Next
    End Select

    'Count how many times it has been modified // just playing with a counter
    If objEvent.TargetInstance.LastModified <> objEvent.PreviousInstance.LastModified Then
        intTmrVal = intTmrVal+1
        WScript.Echo "Changed:        " & intTmrVal & " times"
        WScript.Echo
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: I appreciate the attempt to focus the original question from being "too broad". I attempted to do so. 2 answers were provided, within a day of posting the question, and they are spot-on to working solutions. I would suggest that the question is specific enough to get good answers. Thanks All!

Comment: Thanks for updating the question; glad to hear you got helpful answers. I've voted to reopen your question (but more votes are needed). I flagged the question as too broad at a time when it was, originally. There is no automatic mechanism for notifying close-voters of later edits, so I only just now saw the improved question. You could have notified me _earlier_ with a _comment_ (generally, @-mention users to notify them), and I could have retracted my close vote then. Seeking a dialog usually helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way is to directly set the timeout in the WMI request for the next event

```
Option Explicit

Const MONITOR_FILE = "c:\temp\test.txt"
Const MONITOR_LIMIT = 10

Dim wmi
    Set wmi  = GetObject( "winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2" )

Dim query
    query = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 1 " _ 
            & " WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'CIM_DataFile' " _ 
            & " AND   TargetInstance.Name='" & Replace(MONITOR_FILE, "\", "\\") & "'"

Dim colEvents
    Set colEvents = wmi.ExecNotificationQuery( query )

Dim currentEvent
    Do
        ' Flag value 
        Set currentEvent = Nothing
        ' Try to get the next event with a timeout limit
        ' If a timeout happens we need to catch raised error
        On Error Resume Next 
        Set currentEvent = colEvents.NextEvent( MONITOR_LIMIT * 1000 )
        On Error GoTo 0
        ' If there is not an event there was a timeout
        If currentEvent Is Nothing Then 
            Exit Do
        End If 
    Loop 

    WScript.Echo "File has not been changed for " & MONITOR_LIMIT & " seconds."
```

Answer (score 0):

Event watchers react to events when they occur. You, however, want to react to events that are *not occurring* (namely a file not getting modified). You cannot use an event watcher for that for obvious reasons.

What you need is code that checks the file's last modified date

```
path = "C:\Project\test.txt"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
ts = fso.GetFile(path).DateLastModified
```

and then kills a given process if that timestamp is more than x seconds/minutes

```
pname = "foo.exe"

wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name='" & pname & "'"
If DateDiff("s", ts, Now) > 10 Then
    For Each p In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
        p.Terminate
    Next
End If
```

However, the Windows Task Scheduler doesn't support your desired granularity of running the task every second (or every 2 seconds). And even if it did, spawning a new process every second wouldn't be very good for system performance in the first place. You can set a daily schedule and then instruct Task Scheduler to re-run the task every 5 minutes for the duration of a day. The rest you need to account for in your script.

Define a 5 minute timeout and re-run your check in a loop until that timeout expires:

```
interval = 2 'seconds
timeout  = 5 'minutes

endtime   = DateAdd("n", timeout, Now)
sleeptime = interval * 1000 'milliseconds
Do
    'check and process handling go here
    WScript.Sleep sleeptime
Loop Until Now >= endtime
```

Since `fso` and `wmi` can be re-used don't waste resources by re-defining them over and over again inside the loop. Define them just once at the beginning of the script.